# Why `a` and `b` don't generate the same set of numbers using `mapply` in R?

Tags: r, function, loops, vector, mapply

I'm wondering why `a` and `b` don't generate the same set of numbers in the following:

```
N = 60 ; df = N-1 ; d = 3 ; ncp = d*sqrt(N)

a = mapply(c, as.list(14: d*sqrt(N)+5), as.list(-14: -d*sqrt(N)+5), SIMPLIFY = FALSE) 

b = mapply(c, as.list(14: ncp+5), as.list(-14: -ncp+5), SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```

In other words, I'm asking why `as.list(-14: -d*sqrt(N)+5)` is read differently from `as.list(-14: -ncp+5)`, when `ncp = d*sqrt(N)`?

Comment: Hint: what do those sequences evaluate to?

Comment: It's the precedence of `:` and `*`.  Compare these: `1:2*3` and `1:6`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They don't generate the same numbers because they are not the same due to the order of operations. Let's have a look at the components:

In `a` you have:

```
as.list(-14: -d*sqrt(N)+5)
```

Whereas in `b` you have:

```
as.list(-14: -ncp+5)
```

These are not the same. Let's look:

```
identical(as.list(-14: -ncp+5), as.list(-14: -d*sqrt(N)+5))
```

> ```
> [1] FALSE
> ```

Consider this as a confusion regarding the **order of operations** (precedence).

You thought that everything to the right of the `:` would be evaluated the same in both cases. So, you thought the right hand side of the colon was -18.2379 in both cases. But no!

They didn't teach you in school how the `:` affects evaluation. In fact,

`-d*sqrt(N)+5` is not evaluated as `-ncp+5`. It is evaluated as:

```
(14:-d*sqrt(N))+5
```

or, equivalently:

```
(14:-d)*sqrt(N)+5
```

also, equivalently:

```
(14:-d)*(sqrt(N)+5)
```

Do you see the difference? The `:` comes first. The `+5` and other operations following the `14:-d` are after the `-d*sqrt(N)`. It's added to the sequence that comes from the `:`.

Proof:

```
identical((14:-d)*sqrt(N)+5, 14:-d*sqrt(N)+5)
```

> ```
> [1] TRUE
> ```

```
identical((14:-d*sqrt(N))+5, 14:-d*sqrt(N)+5)
```

> ```
> [1] TRUE
> ```

This was actually a very good question. They don't teach `:` in school when you learn order of operations!

Comment: @Reza I will see if I can make it more clear, one moment. Hopefully this at least makes it clear that it's not a question about `mapply` or the other parst, just about these 2 inner components.

Comment: @Reza I know how to explain it now, 1 sec

Answer (score 0):

Hiding in here is a precedence problem.  `:` has higher precedence than `*`:

```
> 1:2*3
[1] 3 6
> 1:6
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6
```